# Rails Admin and dynamic navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, rails-admin

I've just developed a small engine to allow administrators to create forms and manage their subscriptions.
It consists of essentially two models : Form(title, description) and FormSubscription(form_id, first_name, ...)

As I'm already using RailsAdmin for the whole app administration, I then wondered if it could be possible to use RailsAdmin to manage those subscriptions **by form**.

Let me explain.
Say an admin creates the LaunchPartyRegistration form and people come and register.
What would be wonderful is to have an extra LaunchPartyRegistration tab in the left menu in RailsAdmin which show all the FormSubscriptions for this particular Form (without any way to modify the form_id through the filter menu). And if there is 4 different forms so there would be 4 new tabs in the left menu.

I know there already is the solution of going to the FormSubscription admin page and filter them by form through the filter menu but I feel this is a bit too complicated for a client.

So ... is there a way I can do that with RailsAdmin or am I to do the backend myself ? :)

Cheers !